# Pass command line arguments as well as input from STDIN for Perl script?

Tags: perl, stdin, command-line-arguments, argv

I have a Perl script which takes both command line arguments and STDIN

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $logpath = $ARGV[0];
print "logpath : $logpath\n";

print "Name : ";
my $name = <>;
chomp($name);
print "my name is $name\n";
```

It does not stop at stdin input. 
Works fine for any one of command line or standard input but not for both.

Any Reason?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but what do you want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change

```
my $name = <>;
```

to

```
my $name = <STDIN>;
```

If `@ARGV` has no elements, then the diamond operator will read from `STDIN` but in your case since you are passing arguments though command line, `@ARGV` will not be empty. So when you use the diamond operator `<>` to read the name, the first line from the file whose name is specified on the command line will be read.

Comment: It is a problem because <> reads from files in @ARGV. If you want it to read from stdin instead, then you need to ensure that @ARGV is empty. An alternative way to fix your program is to continue to use <>, but change to: my $logpath = shift; so that @ARGV will be empty.

Comment: Using shift worked for me, whereas changing <> to <STDIN> did not